# Running DllImport commands from CreateRemoteThread

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport, createremotethread

I have a function named `Msg` that's imported from a dll named `tier0.dll`. I can `DllImport` this just fine, but the command only works when the dll is attached to another process which can complete the Msg command. Using `CreateRemoteThread`, it is possible that I could call `Msg` using C# while still letting it have access to the variables of the attached process it needs to complete the command? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later solved this by using [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) to inject a C# dll and use the various Marshal functions with `GetProcAddress` in order to call the other functions.